# Python list processing issue

Tags: python, list

I need to update the first element of list "array" with elements of list "input_array".
prob:
if list "array" is created by type2 it works fine(elements are replaced in every iteration).
If array is created by Type1, all the elements are updated in every iteration.

```
#TYPE1
#----------
array=[]
array_elem=['0.0']
for i in range(3):
    array.append(array_elem)
print array

#TYPE2
#-------
array=[['0.0'],['0.0'],['0.0']]
print array


input_array=['35.0', '20.0', '15.0']
array_position=0
for elem in range(len(input_array)):
    array[elem][array_position]=str(input_array[elem])
    print "result",array

output with Type1:
[['0.0'], ['0.0'], ['0.0']]
[['0.0'], ['0.0'], ['0.0']]
result [['35.0'], ['35.0'], ['35.0']]
result [['20.0'], ['20.0'], ['20.0']]
result [['15.0'], ['15.0'], ['15.0']]


output with Type2:
[['0.0'], ['0.0'], ['0.0']]
[['0.0'], ['0.0'], ['0.0']]
result [['35.0'], ['0.0'], ['0.0']]
result [['35.0'], ['20.0'], ['0.0']]
result [['35.0'], ['20.0'], ['15.0']]
```

I need result as in Type2 .. but the main array will be created dynamically as in Type1.
whats the difference between both the ways of creating list?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code:

```
array=[]
array_elem=['0.0']
for i in range(3):
    array.append(array_elem)
```

Puts the *same* list in `array` three times. To put a *copy* of the list, use slicing:

```
array=[]
array_elem=['0.0']
for i in range(3):
    array.append(array_elem[:])  # <--- [:] makes a copy of the full list
```

Comment: When you say 'array.append(array_elem)' you're copying the identical reference in. If you wrote instead 'array.append(['0']) the problem would go away. If you need to use a variable to initialize the array then use a copy of it, i.e. array.append(copy.copy(array_elem)) . See the copy lib doc.

Comment: This comment seems like it could be its own answer. It's a different, valid, good solution

Answer (score 1):

When you say:

```
array.append(array_elem)
```

you're copying the identical reference in.

If you wrote instead

```
array.append(['0'])
```

the problem would go away. If you need to use a variable to initialize the array then use a copy of it, i.e. array.append(copy.copy(array_elem)) . See the copy lib doc.

Answer (score 0):

Your type1 example creates *references* to your array_elem. So when array_elem is changed from one reference, it changes for all of them. A simplified version of your type1 scenario is this:

```
x = [0.0]
y = x      # x and y now reference the same object
x[0] = 1.0
print(y)

> [1.0]
```

But your type2 example has separate copies of your array_elem:

```
x = [0.0]
y = [0.0]  # x and y reference different objects
x[0] = 1.0
print(y)

> [0.0]
```

You might consider using list comprehensions for your code. The following two examples create *copies* of your array_elem, which matches what you want from your type2 example.

```
array = [[0.0] for _ in range(3)]
```

Or:

```
array = [list(array_elem) for _ in range(3)]
```

Your type1 example is the same as the following shorthand. This code will create references to array_elem:

```
array = [array_elem] * 3
```

Answer (score 0):

1. array_elem: 
    Say this is in address 2000
2. Array
   Code is Array.append(array_elem) for 3 loops
   So 
   This array has reference which can be represented as
   2000
   2000
   2000

Where 2000 is the address of array_elem.

3.input_array=['35.0', '20.0', '15.0']
When “array [elem][array_position]=str(input_array[elem])” is executed.

4.At first loop array will be 
Array [elem][array_position]
Elem:0
Position:0
    a.so array[0][0]=35  ie array[0][0] is referring  2000 which is address of “array_elem” so the value of array_elem is 35. 
    b.This is refelected in the consecutive index of array say index 1 and 2 also refers address 2000 which is address of “array_elem”.

5.This is running for 3 loops at last 15 is reflected.  Thus resulting (15.0, 15.0, 15.0) at last. The value of array_elem will be altered as the loop goes on and ends with 15.

Hope This will solve the issue